# Fail(or rather, Return) fast using functional java

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Apologies for the badly chosen title, couldn't think of a better title. Please feel free to suggest a new title.

I want to write the following piece of code using Java 8 lambda expressions

```
List<Function<MyClass, Optional<String>>> functions //assume initialized
for (final Function<MyClass, Optional<String>> function : functions) {
    final Optional<String> result = function.apply(objectOfMyClass);
    if (result.isPresent()) { //as soon as one of the function returns a non-null string, return
        return result; //
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on how to go about it?

Comment: Is functions a List or a Map?

Comment: It's a List of Functions. There's a typo in there.

Comment: fixed, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
functions.stream()
    .map(f -> f.apply(objectOfMyClass))
    .filter(Optional::isPresent)
    .map(Optional::get)
    .findAny()
```

`findAny` is a [short-circuiting terminal operation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps), which basically means that yes, it short circuits as soon as it finds a valid output.